# Given $x\ y\ +\ x\ z\ +\ *\ y\ z\ *\ +$ recover the tree, write it in usual notation and simplify

Tags: discrete-mathematics, trees, polish-notation

**Given the boolean expression given in reverse Polish notation $$x\ y\ +\ x\ z\ +\ *\ y\ z\ *\ +$$ recover the tree, write it in usual notation and simplify.**

---

The usual notation is

$$\begin{array}{ll}
&x\ y\ +\ x\ z\ +\ *\ y\ z\ *\ +\\
\iff&(x+y)\ x\ z\ +\ *\ y\ z\ *\ +\\
\iff&((x+y)+x)\ z\ *\ y\ z\ *\ +\\
\iff&(((x+y)+x)*z)\ y\ z\ *\ +\\
\iff&(((x+y)+x)*z)\ (y*z)\ +\\
\iff&(((x+y)+x)*z)+(y*z)\\
\end{array}$$

The recovery tree is

[image: Recovery tree]

Finally, the simplification is

$$\begin{array}{ll}
&(((x+y)+x)*z)+(y*z)\\
\iff&(2*x+y)*z+y*z\\
\iff&2*x*z+y*z+y*z\\
\iff&2*z*(x+y)
\end{array}$$

Is that correct? Is it possible to write $2*x\equiv2x$ and so on?

Thanks!

Comment: Your third line is incorrect: $x~z~+$ translates to $(x+z)$ before it is multiplied by $(x+y)$.

Comment: @FabioSomenzi oh, thanks! So it would be $(x+y)*(x+y)+(y*z)$?

Comment: The second $x+y$ is actually $x+z$, and then you can simplify a bit.

Comment: @FabioSomenzi thanks again... Hmmm, we can only do $(x+y)*(x+z)+(y*z)\;=\;x*x+x*z+y*x+y*z+y*z\;=\;x*x+x*z+y*x+2*y*z$, so now it is full simplify?

Comment: It's a Boolean expression, isn't it?  So, $+$ is OR and $*$ is AND.

Comment: @FabioSomenzi yes, the statement says that! So using some Boolean properties: $$\begin{array}{ll}
&((x\vee y)\wedge(x\vee z))\vee(y\wedge z)\\
\iff&x\vee(y\wedge z)\vee(y\wedge z)\\
\iff&x\vee(y\wedge z)
\end{array}$$ Right? If so, do you want to post an answer?

Comment: Right.  You should post the answer, because it's your solution.  I just gave a little nudge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not correct. As [@FabioSomenzi said in comments](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2982593/given-x-y-x-z-y-z-recover-the-tree-write-it-in-usual-nota#comment6155464_2982593), the expression must be $(x+y)*(x+z)+(y*z)$, which has as a tree

[image: Tree]

and after applying some properties ends up with $x\vee(y\wedge z)$.